# Is it possible to generate .s file from Wind River Workbench?

Tags: assembly, compiler-specific, wind-river-workbench

I am looking for possibilities of generating ASM file or instruction trace from Wind River workbench.

Comment: You didn't say what version but in 5.9.3 you can pass in the `-S` to stop compilation and produce an assembly file. This is a command line option at least, you will need to check the workbench guides to determine how to do that in the workbench.

Comment: Got it, thanks @FrankC.